# Using TinyMce with textareas in meta boxes on custom post types

Tags: custom-field, metabox, wp-admin, javascript, tinymce

I am trying to use the http://www.tinymce.com/ plugin to add a tinymce to my textareas in my meta boxes I have created. I've googled other ways and either I cant get it to work or didnt grasp the concept. SO this is what Im trying now --

I tried creating plugin to add the script to my admin dashboard --

```
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_load_scripts'); 
function admin_load_scripts() { 
    $js_file = plugins_url( '/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js', __FILE__ );  
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.tinymce.min', $js_file, array('jquery')); 
}
```

Then I need to call it like so --

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

But im not sure how to do this, being that this is for the backend and not the front end. 
How can I achieve this?

**UPDATED**

This is my code for the meta boxes.
http://pastebin.com/WcC51uA9

I tried the following methods (placing it in functions.php of course), and for the most part they either just didnt work or would show up on the top of the page or on the bottom of the page. They didnt show up on the textarea at all. ---

http://pastebin.com/Ct0mF6q7

http://pastebin.com/R6t0ij6h

http://pastebin.com/dcczcVby

http://pastebin.com/yt1uRS5U

Comment: Why not use the [`wp_editor()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HkzarH7h) with your code included.

Get the old value of the tinyMCE

```
$meta_biography = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_biography', true );
```

Call the TinyMCE Editor

```
wp_editor( $meta_biography, 'biography', array(
    'wpautop'       => true,
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'textarea_name' => 'meta_biography',
    'textarea_rows' => 10,
    'teeny'         => true
) );
```

Save The Editor Value or if nothing is there - delete old values.

```
if( isset( $_POST['meta_biography'] ) && $_POST['meta_biography'] != '' ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_biography', $_POST['meta_biography'] );
} else {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_biography' );
}
```

If you want to add more options to the editor - You can view the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) or Check out this nice [WPTuts Article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-using-wp_editor/). You want to use the `tinymce` and pass it an array of settings. You might have to remove the `teeny => true` in the `wp_editor()` since the Codex says that it will only use minimal editor configuration.

Comment: thanks. One last question I had was, I saw the wptuts article and the settings array, but I didnt see no mention about passing in a settings array for the "kitchen sink". Any ideas on that? I wanted to make an editor for another field that only allows changing the font color.

Comment: @mygm26 - in the WPTuts Article, it is passing `theme_advanced_buttons1` - if you want a second row you can also pass `theme_advanced_buttons2` or howevery many rows you want. In the WPTuts article it also has `wp_adv` at the end of `theme_advanced_buttons1` which you need in order to show your 2nd or 3rd row of buttons. If you're only trying to change the color - might I suggest looking into the Color Picker that's also built into Wordpress.

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks. Is there anyway to hide the kitchen sink on specific instances? I am using the wp editor code for multiple textareas but wanted to hide the kitchen sink on one of them @Howdy_McGee

Comment: @mygm26 That I'm not 100% sure of and was trying to find the answer - you can refer to this question but if you ever figure it out, lemme know how: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117395/tinymce-show-advanced-options-2nd-row-by-default

Answer (score 2):

```
// for pages use 'edit_page_form' as the first parameter. And see my comment below.
add_action( 'edit_form_advanced', 'my_meta_editor' ); 

function my_meta_editor() {

    // set 'your_meta_key' to the actual key
    $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_meta_key', true);

    // only low case [a-z], no hyphens and underscores
    $editor = 'mymetaeditor';

    // See my comment below
    $editor_settings = array();

    wp_editor( $content, $editor, $editor_settings);

}
```

Search [Administrative Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions) for `edit_form_after_title`, `edit_form_after_editor`,  `edit_form_advanced` if you want to change the location of the meta box.

Also see [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) for editor settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Im not sure how to apply this to my situation. Im going to update my answer with the code I am using to create my metaboxes.

Comment: Where ever you want the tinymce you can just say something like: http://pastebin.com/6N5adFip  -- In my experience, this is best put in a large content area, such as below your main Post Editor or what have you.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee ok so if i put the code from the pastebin into my theme functions file, and replace the id, then it will render the editor for that textarea?

Comment: Theoretically yes, all @MaxYudin have given you is ways to show wp_editor(); you should be able to get it working from there. it's pretty straight forward. Otherwise a quick search should yield [many results](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+wp_editor+to+widget&oq=add+wp_editor+to+widget&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4442j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&q=add+wp_editor+to+metabox). Let me know if you are able to get it working!

Comment: I cant get it to work. I tried using this code as well -- `// for pages use 'edit_page_form' as the first parameter. And see my comment below.
add_action( 'edit_form_advanced', 'my_meta_editor' ); 

function my_meta_editor() {

    // set 'your_meta_key' to the actual key
    $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'att_meta_bio', true);

    // only low case [a-z], no hyphens and underscores
    $editor = 'mymetaeditor';

    // See my comment below
    $editor_settings = array();

    wp_editor( $content, $editor, $editor_settings);

}` @Max Yudin @Howdy_McGee

Comment: Paste it to the `functions.php` located in `theme` directory you use.

Comment: Maybe provide a pastebin of your code, with the examples in it - it might just be a small syntax error.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I tried a few methods, and I updated my question with the links to the pastebin's of what I tried.

Comment: @mygm26 I'm not sure why nothing is working for you. I tried to fill in my method into your widgets code which you could give a shot to: http://pastebin.com/HkzarH7h then you get the value via: `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_additional', true);`

Comment: @Howdy_McGee seems to be getting closer, but now the editor seems to be overlaying over other fields, thus not allowing them to be editable. When I try to add text in the bio and hit save it, it doesn't save it. Also the text I had there before I added the code, is not there no more.

Comment: Add some HTML and CSS to give it some spacing, search for "Wordpres Add CSS Admin Panel" and you can make specific styles. Also - my mistake, when you call wp_editor you should pass it `$meta_biography` instead of `$meta_additional` which should save it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Wow thanks! So far everything seems to be working. I had to use clear:both on the editor container and it seems fine. The only thing is how do I add more options for the editor? Such as font color? Also can you put your answer as a answer to the question so I can mark it right?

Answer (score 2):

This function worked perfectly for me just add to your functions.php file and make your custom fields textareas and you are done:

```
//add tinymce editor to custom fields
function admin_add_wysiwyg_custom_field_textarea()
{ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(function($){
        var i=1;
        $('textarea').each(function(e)
        {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          if (!id)
          {
           id = 'customEditor-' + i++;
           $(this).attr('id',id);
          }
          tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, id);
          tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
        });
    });
/* ]]> */</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'admin_add_wysiwyg_custom_field_textarea', 99 );
```

[Taken from here](https://gist.github.com/pragmatic-web/1885364).